# Common server-side and client-side api calls in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http

So I have an isomorphic node based application running (with react). The page is rendered on server first and then the client JS takes over. I am having the data populate first on server (via an api endpoint) and then the same api is being accessed on client side. On the server side I am using "request" library and on the client-side I am using AJAX for fetching the data. I observe that there is duplication in the code I am writing for making api calls on server and client side. Is there a way I can unify this (via some library)?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would just be to set up your build pipelines properly to allow you to share the code. You could then have a `client`, `server`, and `common` directory, and tell your build tools (Webpack, Rollup, Browserify, etc., whatever you may be using) to include everything from `client` and `common` for the front-end, and `common` and `server` for the backend.

There are lots of other ways to deal with it, but that's one of the cleanest. You might also want to take a look at Meteor, which does a lot of what you're talking about for you out-of-the-box (and allows you to use React as a front-end).